# calculating date differences with datetime python

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

Example code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import time

timestamp = 1620013967000

cunix = int(time.time())
ounix = timestamp / 1000

outc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ounix)
cutc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(cunix)

#time_diff = cutc_time - outc_time

if condition == met:
    if(outc_time + relativedelta(months=+6) - cutc_time) >= 1: # This doesn't work but I'm trying to give an idea of what I would like to accomplish.
        do_stuff()
```

An example of the output I'm getting currently with these variables:

```
143 days, 6:53:04
162 days, 11:42:26
122 days, 19:31:56
131 days, 20:38:03
6 days, 21:03:03
12 days, 3:41:45
159 days, 5:48:15
159 days, 14:37:54
50 days, 0:04:41
153 days, 13:43:03
```

Basically what I want is an idea on how to make a condition where it'll only proceed if the difference in days is equal to or less than 1. I'm a little lost on how to do it currently. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `>= 1`, `>= timedelta(days=1)`? Other than that, please think about how to make your code example a [mre]. As it stands, there's unused variables, undefined variables etc. - which makes it kind of hard (for me) to get the point.

Comment: also note: [utcfromtimestamp can be missleading](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html)

Comment: You say equal to or less than, do you really mean that? Your code is looking for *greater than or equal to 1*, which seems like the reverse of what you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

timestamp = 1620013967000

cunix = int(time.time())
ounix = timestamp / 1000

outc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ounix)
cutc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(cunix)

diff = cutc_time - outc_time

if diff >= timedelta(days=1):
    print("hey")
```

As @Blckknght pointed out you say less than or equal to 1, but your code uses greater than. Either way, just change the symbol in the `if` statement above.

Also, is utc necessary for your code? For this example `utcfromtimestamp` could just be replaced with `fromtimestamp`.